# How to save numpy array in keras layer's call method

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I use tensorflow 2.1 with customize layer as follow:

```
class Mylayer(KL.layer):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Mylayer, self).__init__(name)
        self.conv = KL.Conv2D(32)

    def call(self, inputs):
        outputs = self.conv(inputs)
        np.save('outputs.npy', outputs)
        return outputs
```

However, whether I decorate tf.function at train_step or not, `np.save` says cannot convert a symbolic tensor to numpy array. If I change to `np.save('outputs.txt', outputs.numpy())` without using tf.function, it shows that tensor object has no attribute numpy. Also, `call()` function seems to be called twice with symbolic tensor in first time and eager tensor in second time when not using tf.function.

How do I save the tensor value inside call()?

Comment: Why not just save the output, and not from inside of the call method?

Comment: Because I use pretrained weight from pytorch version, and I want to verify all outputs layer by layer

Comment: I don't understand how that that changes anything. You have a MyLayer, when you create the model that uses it, grab it's output, and add that as an output to the model.

Comment: MyLayer is just an example. The  actual layer which is implemented by me is OctConv(https://github.com/facebookresearch/OctConv). My model consists of series of OctConvs. Terefore, gathering all high/low frequency outputs makes model's outputs very large.

Comment: In practice, the actually method call doesn't get called much. It just helps create the graph. If you cannot handle so many outputs at one time, then you might separate your model into multiple models, and chain the outputs. Sounds like a pain, and I am curious to see if you get a good answer to this question. You might also look into how tensorboard is handling this, because it will let you monitor tensors.

Answer (score 1):

Keras models are implicitly compiled into static graphs, whether you use `@tf.function` in the call method or not. Consequently, all tensors are of type `tf.Tensor` and not of type `tf.EagerTensor` and therefore don't have the `numpy()` method.

To overcome this, simply pass `dynamic=True` to the constructor of the model that uses the layer. You will then be able to use the `numpy()` method

But remember, doing so may significantly increase training and inference times.

Comment: I only find `dynamic` in layer's constructor and `run_eagerly` as model's property. Should I set `dynamic=True` for each layer, or set  `run_eagerly` for whole model is enough?

Comment: `run_eagerly` for the whole model is enough.